# MATLAB: Gaussian RV

Tags: matlab, gaussian

So... I am working on part b and I haven no idea what this question is asking me to do. Does it want me to plot the actual `Q(x)` equation graph with part a graphs?
[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you need to plot the `pdf(x)` and `cdf(x)` and compare to the estimated pdf and cdf you obtained for the different values of `t`.